# SQL Server Add Calculated Column with WHILE loop

Tags: sql-server, database, while-loop, calculated-columns

I'm supposed to have a column that automatically updates the debt of each member, per year

The old debt used to be 60,000 until the year 2013, after that it became 75,000

There's also an "Activity" column that I use in the program, if the member is still active, it's set to "YES", if he stopped, it's changed to "NO"
There's also ANOTHER Column called "pDebt" which stands for Paid Debt

The basic formula behind it is a simple AmountOfDebt - PaidDebt (AKA @Amount - pDebt)

I tried to make that new table, but I was having 2 problems

1. The columns (l.7 "dateOfRegistration" & l.10 "Activity") keep giving the famous "Invalid Column Name" while being existing and already being used in other calculated columns

   PS: yes I did use Ctrl + Shift + R, I did save the query, restart SQL Server many times, it still shows, so I'm guessing there's an input problem
2. I can't connect my WHILE loop to the ADD function to add the new table.

Here's my code,

```
Use [Project Alpha1]
GO

BEGIN

DECLARE @Amount MONEY = 0,
@IndividualYear int = YEAR([dateOfRegistration])

ALTER TABLE initialTable
ADD fDebt1 AS (WHILE (@IndividualYear < GETDATE() AND [Activity] = 'YES')
BEGIN
    IF @IndividualYear = 1998 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 1999 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2000 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2001 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2002 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2003 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2004 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2005 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2006 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2007 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2008 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2009 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2010 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2011 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2012 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
    IF @IndividualYear = 2013 SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
    Else
        SET @Amount = @Amount + 75000

    SET @IndividualYear = @IndividualYear + 1
END
@Amount - pDebt)
```

I'm sorry, I know I didn't type the end of the code properly (the last line saying @Amount - pDebt), but since my WHILE loop wasn't working, I didn't really think it was necessary to work it through until the end properly either

**This is made on SQL Server**

Thank you for reading guys, I'd appreciate even the slightest help.

Comment: This sounds like a very weird design to me. I imagine they make payments as well and you track individual payments, so you'd have some sort of ledger table. Why not set up a SQL job that runs that inserts debt records instead of recalculating a couple of fields? That way, that table would always provide an account balance.

Answer (score 1):

One method is to wrap your logic/calculations in a scalar function so that your calculated field just calls the function. It will be easier to test that way as well.

```
ALTER TABLE initialTable ADD fDebt1 AS dbo.f_CalculateDebt([RegistrationDate], [Activity], [Debt])
```

Then your scalar function could look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_CalculateDebt(
    @RegistrationDate DATETIME,
    @Activity NVARCHAR(100),
    @Debt MONEY
) 
RETURNS MONEY
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        @Amount MONEY = 0,
        @IndividualYear INT = YEAR(@RegistrationDate)
    WHILE (@IndividualYear < YEAR(GETDATE()) AND @Activity = 'YES') BEGIN
        IF @IndividualYear = 1998
            SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000
        -- Removed for readability --
        ELSE IF @IndividualYear = 2013
            SET @Amount = @Amount + 60000 
        ELSE
            SET @Amount = @Amount + 75000
        SET @IndividualYear = @IndividualYear + 1
    END
    RETURN @Amount - @Debt
END
GO
```